# How to read and modify a text file based on some condition

Tags: java, file-io

How can I read an existing text file and modify some of its value based on some condition like if I get some text like

Apple 1 3 5

Now, here whenever I get an integer value I have to increase its count by 1 and save back to the same file again.

For example, if I read some content like above I should be able to save

Apple 2 4 6

back to the same file again

My code looks like

try{
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:\Apple.txt",true);

```
        FileReader inputFileReader   = new FileReader("c:\\Apple.txt");
        BufferedReader inputStream   = new BufferedReader(inputFileReader);
        PrintWriter    outputStream  = new PrintWriter(fstream);



        while((inline=inputStream.readLine())!=null)
        {
            values=inline.split("-");

            Integer l = Integer.parseInt(values[2])+1;
            outputStream.print((inline.replaceAll(values[2],l.toString())));

        }

        outputStream.close();


    }
```

So, I get an output like

Apple 1 3 5 Apple 1 4 5

But my required output is

Apple 1 4 5

Thanks in advace

Comment: Have you writen any code yourself? Show where you are stuck and we can help

Comment: delete your comments and append your code to the question

Comment: @Jose K I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it interactively on the same file (or at least maybe you can but it would be really tricky).. you could

- open the input file
- open the output file
- for each line in file

  - check your condition, if true

    - generate the new line according to what you are going to modify
    - save it on output file
  - if false

    - copy the line into new file without modifying it
- close both files
- delete first one and rename second one to first (you can do it easily with API functions)

Answer (score 1):

Split your code into separate method calls:

```
File f = getFile();
String text = getFileContents(f);
if(matchesRequirements(text)){
    String newText = performReplacements(text);
    writeFile(newText, f);
}
```

Now you can implement these methods:

```
private static void writeFile(String newText, File f){
    // TODO implement this method
}

private static String performReplacements(String text){
    // TODO implement this method
    return null;
}

private static boolean matchesRequirements(String text){
    // TODO implement this method
    return false;
}

private static String getFileContents(File f){
    // TODO implement this method
    return null;
}

private static File getFile(){
    // TODO implement this method
    return null;
}
```

See how far you get and ask specific questions where you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I used RandomAccessFile and it works fine.